# "Улыбаемся и машем" — происхождение мема

Tags: фразеология, цитата

Скажите, пожалуйста, откуда пошло выражение "Улыбаемся и машем", которое из интернет-мема превратилось уже в поговорку?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это из мультика "Мадагаскар". Диалог пингвинов.

> — Шкипер, а может, сказать им, что топлива у нас не осталось?
> — Нет, улыбаемся и машем, парни. Улыбаемся и машем.